# How to get all rows from the table except header row?

Tags: javascript, html

I have table created dynamically in JavaScript.

I have this table:

[image]

Here the way how I get rows from the table above:

```
var trows = table.rows;
```

This way I get all the rows from the table above including the header row.
My question is there any way to get all rows from the table except header row?

Comment: Good practice is to use HTML structure as it is intended, this will make selections easier for you:
`<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><!-- Header row cells --></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Body rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all those rows inside `<tbody>` and put the header inside `<thead>` Then do

```
var trows = document.getElementById('tableid').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove first value of an array with `.shift`

```
trows.shift(); // remove first line
```

Answer (score 1):

before answering your, i would like to suggest to construct the  table structure as given below so that you can get result what you exactly needed.

```
    <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>heading</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
     <tbody id="tableid">
       <tr>
          <td>data1</td>
          <td>data2</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

And then in your script,now you can get the result as follow

```
var trows = table.rows;
```

i hope you might be satisfied with this answer, if not post a question without any hesitation. thank you